# Access to API data when some of the values begins with an underscore?

Tags: javascript, object, frontend

I have the following data from an API
[Link from data from de api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sksv.png)

I need to access into ***product_last_data*** but I don't know how to access because of the element '_source' with the underscore at the beginning

I've been trying the following:

```
response.data.data (This works fine)
```

But when I try to access to any element with the underscore I don't know how to do it I've been trying this:

```
response.data.data['_source']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.data.data` is an array of objects, so you need to iterate the array (or pick a single element) to access the objects underneath. For example:

```
response.data.data.forEach(o => console.log(o._source.product_last_data))
```

or

```
console.log(response.data.data[0]._source.product_last_data)
```

Note that `_source` is a valid key which does not require `[]` notation to access.

Comment: Thanks, I used map to solve this, your answer helped a lot